# Can small amounts of neutron star matter or similar neutron-degenerate matter be (briefly) produced by radiation implosion or similar methods?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, neutron-stars

Today, a variety of methods are used to implode pellets of fusion fuel in order to perform inertial-confinement fusion. The pellets explode apart in microseconds whether or not fusion actually happens, but for a brief moment the fuel is compressed to a degree not usually seen in condensed matter.

This is the method used in experiments such as Z-pinch fusion, the National Ignition Facility using converging pulsed lasers, and the radiation implosion method in which reflected radiation and plasma from a fission bomb is used to compress a fusion bomb's core to the point of fusion.

What I wonder is whether this same principle could be used, on a suitably adapted and vastly increased scale, to (briefly) produce small quantities of neutron star matter without the involvement of gravity -- or, alternatively, is there a particular reason (such as adiabatic heating) that this *cannot* work?

Comment: Studies are going on in accelerators on quark gluon plasma, a stage further than neutron stars. This requires ion-ion collisions at high energy., which would be also necessary to create the "matter" you want . I do not think the type of experiment you mention  can achieve the necessary energies. see this which tries to use quark gluon plasma information in neutron star https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4874102

Comment: @annav I suppose that's a good point, though I tended to consider particle accelerators (where only a few particles are collided at a time) to be different  from imploding an entire microgram quantity of condensed matter or dense gas. Though I wonder if this is a distinction without a difference.